# How to turn array of strings into 2 dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to turn `["0,1", "0,1", "1,2"]` into `[[0,1], [0,1], [1,2]]`. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `map()`, `split()`, and `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array#map` along with `String#split`.

```js
const arr = ["0,1", "0,1", "1,2"];
const res = arr.map(x => x.split(",").map(Number));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.map()` and `.split()` with `.parseInt()` or use `+`:

```js
console.log(
  ["0,1", "0,1", "1,2"]
    .map(i => i.split(",")
      .map(n => +n)
    )
);
```

Comment: What does `.trim()` have to do with it? Do you mean `parseInt()`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes! Sorry! Thanks for the comment.